# Spring Batch 3.0.2 integration with Spring Core 4.1.x - What is the appropriate way to use @EnableBatchProcessing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to run Spring Batch Admin app with Spring Boot and it looks like that I have the same issue. Preferred solution would be to use Java configuration, instead of XML.

What would be appropriate solution to use @EnableBatchProcessing with Spring Batch Admin?

I had a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139100/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-spring-batch-admin-and-spring-boot-properly), but I wasn't able to solve the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Spring Batch configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml",
        "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"
    })
public class BatchConfig {
}
```

Spring Boot starter implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import(BatchConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return super.configure(application);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4421fb40 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at some.package.Application.main(FeedApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4421fb40 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4421fb40 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6187a2.jobRepository(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.jobBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:58) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6187a2.CGLIB$jobBuilders$8(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6187a2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$606382af.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6187a2.jobBuilders(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example (`@EnableBatchProcessing` is removed, `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` are created in Java configuration):

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(
        value = {
                "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml",
                "classpath:org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"
        }
    )
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: How in the world you found that out? I could not understand at all by looking at logs that this should solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because `@EnableBatchProcessing` registers a `StepScope` and so does Spring Batch Admin.  As I mentioned in the post you referenced, I would not recommend using `@EnableBatchProcessing` with Spring Batch Admin and instead, just configure the beans you need (only the job factory and step factory).

Comment: That helped. Thanks.

But now no jobs are shown in Spring Batch Admin UI (jobs and steps are created in Java, not defined in XML).

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: It works, there was an issue with package scan. I will post working solution example. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Michael, is there an update on the fix? When is the scheduled release date for the version with the fix?

Comment: The current snapshot of Spring Batch Admin (and I believe 2.0.0.M1) both have the fix so that if you don't use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, everything should work (you get the builders, etc automatically configured)

Comment: Using latest Spring Batch Admin version 2.0.0.M1 and removing @EnableBatchProcessing annotation worked for me.