# How to integrate spring batch admin console

Tags: spring-batch, jhipster, spring-batch-admin

I'm using jhipster and I want to integrate spring batch admin console in my webapp. (http://localhost:8080/batch-console for example)

I tried to integrate the following response in my jhipster webapp [Is there a way to integrate spring-batch-admin and spring-boot properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139100/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-spring-batch-admin-and-spring-boot-properly) but I get the following error (properties seems to be not loaded)

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.name' in string value "${spring.application.name}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.JhipsterApp.main(JhipsterApp.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.name' in string value "${spring.application.name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

If I hard code these properties for testing, my jhipster application starts but I get :

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden

What do I need to doexactly to integrate spring batch admin in my Jhipster app?

Do I need to add the following dependency to my pom?

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring boot version : 1.4.1.RELEASE
Jhipster version : 3.8.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add spring-boot. JHipster is a spring-boot app. As for [spring-batch-admin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin) for what I see in the documentation is a web UI using Spring MVC which actualy is also a part of the JHipster stack, but JHipster is using as a client a single page app with AngularJS  wich is consuming REST services, i.e. you can have some issue when integrating your batch-admin app.

Your

*Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ Request Method:GET Status Code:403 Forbidden*  it indicates that there are some changing at your authorization since 
http://localhost:8080/ is the normal entry point in a JHipster app.

As a solution I will recommend to use the [micro service approach](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/). The documentation of spring-batch-admin indicates that there is RESTful (JSON) API. This will perfectly fits into micro services app.

Comment: I was thinking of using microservice architecture bu my jhipster app (jhipster app of my customer) is a monolithic app. Following https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot I m able to use spring batch admin with spring boot app, so I thought it was possible to use it with jhipster in a monolithic architecure but I get the errors mentionned above. Do you have any idea/recommandation?

Comment: After a look at the sugested  expample project  I can say that the integration with spring-boot was mainly to use an embeded Tomcat. The spring-batch-admin from what I see is a ui for spring-batch. This ui is not using AngularJS and JHipster ui is using AngularJS. So you will need to have a look of what REST API is porvinding spring-batch-admin and try to consume them in the JHipster ui. Also you need to have a look at spring-batch-admin to not overide configuration, e.g. authorization, entry-point in the app, of JHipster. Maybe you could start the integration with JHipster as a plugin.

Comment: thanks for your reply and suggestions, I will take a look at plugin suggestion. But I have already integrated Spring batch admin in a webapp builded with extjs frontend but it was not a spring boot app and the config was an xml config (servlet mapping added to to web.xml). So I think it is possible to integrate it with angularjs app ( jhipster app) but I don't know how.... If you find a solution.... I will be happy to read it.